# PHP mysqli random error during insert

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, drupal-7

I migrate data from a mysql database to another mysql database with different schema using a PHP script. The entity currently I am working on is very simple. It is users data. All of my database tables have `utf8_general_ci` collation to support Arabic text.

I may receive the following error:

> Failed to run query #14: (1064) You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near 'ايمان مصطفى', '1425827057', 0, 0, 1,
>   'Africa/Cairo', '', 0)' at line 1

The unexpected thing here: When I delete the newly added records to the destination database before the stop due to the error and running my script again, I got the same error but for another record!

In the error regarded above you may notice that the Arabic name `ايمان مصطفى` in the query is missing one of the two single quote `'`. However, I'm sure that my script enclose the values with single quotes as the following:

```
$sqlFormat = "INSERT INTO users (uid, name, pass, theme, signature, created, access, login, status, timezone, language, picture) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '', '%s', '%s', 0, 0, 1, '%s', '', 0)";
    $sql = sprintf($sqlFormat, $user['uid'], $user['name'], $user['pass'], $user['signature'], $user['created'], $user['timezone']);
    $res2 = mysqli_query($db2, $sql);
    if (!$res2) {
        echo "Failed to run query #$i: (" . $db2->errno . ") " . $db2->error;
        echo "\n";
        echo $sqlInsert;
        if ($db2->errno != 1062) {
            exit();
        }
```

#### Edit

This is an example for the random error generated with a printout for the `INSERT` sql statement delivered to the query:

```
Failed to run query #4: (1064) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'عبد العزيز كحيل', '1425828804', 0, 0, 1, 'Africa/Cairo', '', 0)' at line 1

INSERT INTO users (uid, name, pass, theme, signature, created, access, login, status, timezone, language, picture) VALUES ('149', 'عبد العزيز كحيل', 'U.GCK9X7@$7-w$1@lZQ5HZ=x}M(@a5D}<`Cdod13aJ8O/&&>0%w7jUrKm[bX\', '', 'عبد العزيز كحيل', '1425828804', 0, 0, 1, 'Africa/Cairo', '', 0)
```

You may notice that the Arabic name `عبد العزيز كحيل` is surrounded correctly with two single quotes for the value for `name` field, but it is missing a trailing single quote for the `signature` field.

My problems are:

- I need to know why this error is generated randomly?
- How to avoid this error?

Comment: Best way to eliminate that error is to use bind variables for the values you want to insert

Comment: you might want to print out $sql on the error failure. It could be that you're not properly escaping the strings you're inserting into the database.

Comment: That error message does not correspond with the SQL you have shown.  For example, in the error message, the fourth-from-last value was the string `'1425827057'` whereas the SQL contains the constant integer `1`.

Comment: I regarded another error with its SQL printout.

Comment: @MarkBaker Could you tell me a resource link for using bind please.

Comment: From the [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: FWIW, the query that you have added in your edit is failing because of the value `'U.GCK9X7@$7-w$1@lZQ5HZ=x}M(@a5D}<\`Cdod13aJ8O/&&>0%w7jUrKm[bX\'` which (as you can see) isn't properly terminated because of its trailing ``\`` character, which erroneously *escapes* the closing string quote `'`. If you're not parameterising your statements (as you really ought to be doing), you **must** pass string literals through [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) before concatenating them into your SQL—to avoid not only these problems, but also SQL injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't really tell you why this happens, i guess some charset-issue with this language. Is your script saved as UTF-8, your database UTF-8 and your connection also UTF-8?

One way (the best in my opionion) is to use PreparedStatements. Instead of filling the values in yourself, let the Database do the job. Since you're already using sprintf, you'll easily understand how PreparedStatements work, since they use a similar syntax and work similar. The difference is, that you don't fill your values in directly, but send this Query as-is to the database and then send your values one by one afterwards.

Take a look at [mysqli::prepare](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.prepare.php), the examples show how to handle prepared-statements with mysqli.